# Phone number mapped to '0000000000'

Tags: m2e, m2epro, ebay

## Situation

We are using [m2epro in version 6.3.7](http://docs.m2epro.com/display/ReleaseNotes/M2E+Pro+Version+-+6.3.7) on a magento 1.9.0 and we are facing a little problem with mapping phone numbers from ebay to magento orders. In Ebay the information is setup with a non prefixed phone number, like in the first image *(Ebay: Buyer details)*.

[image: Ebay: Buyer details (valid phone number, without prefix)]

However, in magento orders the phone number is replaced with the bogus value of 0000000000, as shown in the second image *(Magento: Sales > Orders)*.

[image: Magento: Sales > Orders]

This holds for both; the shipping and the billing address.

## Analysis

As we understand it correctly, ebay orders are delivered in a two step process which moves data through m2e before they end up in magento: **`ebay --1--> m2e --2--> magento`**. Thus, the phone number must being corrupted somewhere in step `1` or `2`. Nonetheless, we assume the error occurs in step `1`, because the orders in m2e all have an `Invalid Request` set as their Telephone number as in the image *(Magento: Sales on ebay > Sales > Edit shipping address)*:

[image: Magento: Sales on ebay > Sales > Edit shipping address]

## Code Reference

Searching this bogus value in the m2e codebase, reveals three possible reads in following Files:

- `\Ess_M2ePro_Model_Buy_Order_ShippingAddress`
- `\Ess_M2ePro_Model_Ebay_Order_ShippingAddress`
- `\Ess_M2ePro_Model_Amazon_Order_ShippingAddress`

## Code

Each of these reads set `'0000000000'` as the default phone number, when the phone otherwise would be equal to the empty string `''`.

```
private function getPhone()
{
    $phone = $this->getData('phone');

    if ($phone == '') {
        $phone = '0000000000';
    }

    return $phone;
}
```

## Question

Does anybody have encountered a similar problem before and knows a solution to this? So, if there is a valid<sup>1</sup> phone number present in ebay, that it is delivered correctly to magento? Any debugging suggestions are welcome as well, e.g. : Is it anyhow possible to configure the m2e logging, so that it outputs errors numbers returned by calls to the [ebay APIs](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/errors/errormessages.htm)?

<sup>1</sup>valid: *a phone number with or without prefix, not being empty.*

## Research

The [changelog on m2e](http://docs.m2epro.com/display/ReleaseNotes/Home) doesn't include any fixes on this behalf. Looking for answers on the stackexchange networks didn't match anything useful either.